# How do I use MariaDB together with Rails on Windows 10?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mariadb

I want to make a Rails app on Windows and decided to use MariaDB after finding out that Rails supports it since a few years ago. But all the tutorials are about using them together on Linux. Is it possible to do the same thing on Windows? I already have MySQL installed and started an app using it but I wnat to change it to MariaDB. What should I do?

Comment: If MariaDB is installed on Windows there should not be any problem?

Comment: I would ask myself if you are going to be deploying your app to windows in production. In most cases the answer is no. So it makes a a lot more sense to develop on some sort of virtual machine running linux which will also save you a lot of pain as windows support is not considered a priority in the Ruby world and all the learning resources are written for *nix.

Comment: assuming you've managed to install and use rails with mysql - you should be able to update your `database.yml` file to the new MariaDB instance. https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-mysql-or-mariadb-database